# couchdb 1.3.x and couch_httpd_auth.proxy_use_secret

Tags: couchdb, iriscouch

I'm currently running couchdb 1.3 over iriscouch.

I need to the [proxy authentication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html?highlight=oauth#proxy-authentication) feature but I don't manage to set:

```
couch_httpd_auth.proxy_use_secret = true
```

in the config...

Does anyone know from which version of couchdb this feature is supported?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proxy authentication is supported as of couchdb 1.5